# Amazon MQ Connection getting timed out in Java

Tags: amazon-web-services, activemq-classic

I have created a amazon mq broker in AWS and when creating a connection to it via open wire protocol, it is getting timed out.
I have added the inbound rule for security group with my public IP.
Broker is active/standby & has status as Running.

Followed example in the below url:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/amazon-mq-working-java-example.html#quick-start-prerequisites

Tried the url in both ways:

```
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("ssl://b-bfd44b26-3472-45b5-953c-880fa7259d35-1.mq.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:61617");

Exception in thread "main" javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: ssl://b-bfd44b26-3472-45b5-953c-880fa7259d35-1.mq.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:61617. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

and

```
private final static String WIRE_LEVEL_ENDPOINT 
            = "failover:(ssl://b-bfd44b26-3472-45b5-953c-880fa7259d35-1.mq.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:61617,ssl://b-bfd44b26-3472-45b5-953c-880fa7259d35-2.mq.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:61617)?randomize=true";
final ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
                new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(WIRE_LEVEL_ENDPOINT);
```

No exception, but it is like doing nothing.

what can be the reason for the exception? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in the SG (Security group) attached to the Amazon MQ has port 8162 and 61617 enabled for your https and openwire connection in InBound for "Custom TCP". Choose 'My Ip' to get your ip.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/amazon-mq-working-java-example.html#quick-start-prerequisites